Pessure required for pumping seawater through pipe with inlet at a depth below sea level
I need to calculate the head capacity required at the pump, to pump sea water from a depth of 100m below sea level i.e. inlet is at 100m below sea level, the recieving end is at 5m above sea level. The flow rate shall be 100 litres/second. Length of the pipeline is 500m, inner diameter of the pipe is 800mm.
I believe that the potential head that the pump is just 5m and not 100m+5m, because water rises up to mean sea level without any effort from the pump. Is my thought correct, or should water be pumped with certain potential head to attain the required flow rate and how is it calculated?
Total head will be potential head + head loss due to friction + head due to desired delivery pressure at outlet

Where is the pump?

water rises up to mean sea level without any effort from the pump ... that is not quite true ... temperature and salinity affect the density of the water

@Solar Mike : the pump is at 5m above sea level at the outlet end.

@jsotola: can you explain more, does it mean that the pump must suck water up. The pump is at the outlet end which is at 5m above sea level.

if the water at the 100 m depth is more dense than the surface water, then yes ... you also have to take the friction of the pipe into account

@jsotola: Thank you for your answer. What if the density at the surface is 1024kg/m^3 and at 100m depth it is 1025kg/m^3, then the potential head required at the pump will be difference in density*difference in height between inlet and mean sea level + density of sea water from 100m depth * height above sea level
i.e. (1025-1024)100+10255. correct? Ofcourse head due to friction needs to be added as well to find the total head at the pump. Appreciate a reply, thank you once again!

"... the pump is at 5m above sea level at the outlet end." Just a thought: Will you need to prime the pump? An impeller pump won't suck air to prime itself.

@Transistor: thank you, yes probably priming is required. The choice of pump is not something I am keen or looking for. I am trying to confirm with others if my understanding of potential head at the pump.
